# Connect to Progress database without knowing user and password

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

Setup: Progress 11.5 databases sitting on Linux (CentOS) server, with proenv available.

I'm trying to connect to Progress database through proenv and sqlexp. I'm unable to, since I don't know the user and password. There's no way I can obtain it from someone else, as nobody knows these credentials. I have root access on this server.

How can I connect to this database so that I can later create another account to use through ODBC?

What I've tried already is:

Being on `root` account, opening up proenv by

```
/dlcloc/dlc-11.5/bin/proenv
```

which brings up proenv, and then when I try

```
sqlexp -db rep -H localhost -S 2502 {-user ?? -password ??}
```

given that there's a db within

```
/dbloc/prod/rep/
```

with files like `rep.db, rep.lg, rep.b1, rep.d1` and some other files avilable on localhost under port 2502 (confirmed through `ps aux | grep rep`)

I get an error even without user and password

> Error: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Access denied(Authorisation failed). (8933)

Which is obvious from my side, but there's no way to get user and password. How can I go around this given my environment to be able to establish a successfull connection?

Additional note: There's a special user called `progressuser` under which database is created, but impersonating that user from root as `su progressuser` and going through the same process yields the same results.

Comment: User sysprogress password sysprogress doesn't work, in case someone was wondering :)

Comment: It would be helpful to know what licenses you have available. Many workarounds will depend on being able to make a 4gl client connection of some sort. To determine what licenses you have run the "showcfg" utility from your proenv prompt. (If you post the information you might want to redact the serial numbers and license keys.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try accessing the database using the native 4GL broker. And possibly try this solution:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P9483

First run that proenv-script, it will set paths and environment variables.

Then identify on which port the 4GL broker runs. If you dont know: check your database log file (rep.lg). Look for something like:

```
[YYYY/MM/DD@HH:MM:SS.sss+TZ] P-XXXX       T-YYYY I BROKER  0: (4262)  Servicename (-S): NNNN.
```

The Ns will be your port. It might possibly be a service name to check in /etc/services

Then access the Progress Editor with a connected database:

```
pro -db rep -H <IP-address/domain name> -S <port number/service name>
```

You should see a rudimentary editor. To run something you press Ctrl+X or F1. To access the menu F3. To exit something F4.

Access the Menu using F3 and arrow-key your way to Tools -> Datadictionary. Now you should be able to follow the steps in the link provided above.

Perhaps its a good idea to make sure you have a valid backup before you start messing around with the users...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please let me know what you mean by "_First run that proenv-script, it will set paths and environment variables._" - what script?

Comment: We might be onto something. When I launched `pro` as you mentioned, I get a _Only SQL clients allowed on this Broker_ error

Comment: 1. Basically run ”proenv”. 2 4GL connections might be turned off, thats too bad in that case

Comment: You might have specified the SQL broker with -S, make sure that you are using a 4GL broker as Jensd suggests. If you are logged in on the same server you could also simply drop -S and -H and connect via shared memory.